# what is the purpose of ".push" in this line "@errorLogin.push("Username should not be blank")" of code

Tags: ruby

Here is the code below:

I wanted to know the purpose of `.push` in this line: `@errorLogin.push("Username should not be blank")`

```
def loginValidations(errorLogin)
   puts"inside loginValidations"
   loginUsername = @params["username"]
   puts "loginUsername: #{loginUsername}"
   loginPass = @params["password"]
   puts "loginPass: #{loginPass}"
   logFlag=true
   #count=0
   if loginUsername == nil || loginUsername == ""
     @errorLogin.push("Username should not be blank")
     logFlag=false
   end
   #count=count+1
   if loginPass == nil || loginPass == ""
     @errorLogin.push("Password should not be blank")
     logFlag=false
   end
end
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-push

Comment: I have just started learning Ruby, Rhomobile. Please share some needful links so that i can better understand Ruby as there are very less resources available online to learn Ruby.

Comment: "I did not find any documentation on '.push' in Ruby"...  if you google "push Ruby" you'll get loads of documentation. Every single entry on that first Google page usefully describes "push".

Comment: I am working on "Login Form validation" for mobile app in Rhomobile..Is there any other way to perform server side validation using ruby instead of using the code I have mentioned above.?

Answer (score 2):

`Array#push` inserts an element at the end of the array.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.push 4
# a = [1,2,3,4]
```

In that case probably that line inserts a failed validation in a variable that keeps track of login errors.